# Sync shared library projects/modules with its source

Tags: android

I am learning to build Android shared libraries that can be used with different projects. I got a few questions regarding this subject. Before I go into the questions, below is what I have done so far:

- Create a library project
- Create another application project and import above library as a module

My questions are:

- Is the library project's code automatically synchronized with the one imported into application projects? How it can be achieved?
- If not, what else I can do to make sure I just need to update the shared library once?

I am using Android Studio IDE.

Thank you,

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ah yes, this can be very helpful in many cases. You can do the following to achieve this.

Let's say you have two projects - **MyApplication** and **MyLibraryDemo** containing the library module **libmodule** with the following paths:

**MyApplication** - `"/../AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication"`

**MyLibraryDemo** - `"/../AndroidStudioProjects/MyLibraryDemo"`

**libmodule** - `"/../AndroidStudioProjects/MyLibraryDemo/libmodule"`

And let's say you are trying to use **libmodule** in **MyApplication**. 
Then, in your `settings.gradle` of your `MyApplication` project, do this

```
include ':app', ":libmodule"
project(':libmodule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../MyLibraryDemo/libmodule')
```

You may have to make relevant corrections, but I hope the idea of linking another module is clear.

All the best :)

Comment: This works like a charm. Two modules are automatically sync'ed, I don't need to open both of them when I want to update the shared module.

Comment: What is `:app` folder and `settingsDir` here

Comment: Is there a way to include the external projects but not to include the full path so they can be used on other PCs as well?

Comment: @Esteban You can use the relative path to the other project as shown in the answer

Comment: For me the subproject indeed builds, but I cannot reference it as a dependency `Error:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':libmodule' (needed by module 'app'.)` when I declare it like this `compile project(':libmodule')`

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for a Kotlin version: project(":libmodule").projectDir = File("../MyLibraryDemo/libmodule")

Answer (score 7):

Importing a module from outside of your application project creates a copy of the library inside of your application. If your system supports it, creating a symbolic link will allow you to have only one copy of the code.

Otherwise, you can move the entire library project into your application and add it to your settings.gradle.

If you wish to have separate git repositories for both of these projects, look into using git submodules.