# Add external project dependency in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am starting to migrate from ANT to `Gradle` and I have multiple projects which rely on one another. They are not all in the same path, meaning that they are not all under a single project but still they have dependencies with one another.

I read that in `Gradle` in order to define a dependency between two projects, they need to be under the same root project.

Can I avoid this?
how can I give `project compile(..)` a path which is outside of the current path?

In other words, I don't want to start changing the path of the projects, for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you understand basics of grade file structure in the project.

Refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358724/sync-shared-library-projects-modules-with-its-source/31524641#31524641) for a solution to getting external library projects to compile into your main project.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: it works! and a smaller question, i am using gradle eclipse plugin, and when i click "refresh all" in the gradle menu, the projects in the build path are deleted, and only after i run the 'eclipse' task then the projects in the build path are back. this is how its supposed to be?

Comment: Yes Avra, this how its supposed to be. `Build` files are generated at every run entirely from your code. Your code is safe. In fact, you should ignore `build` directory while implementing any version control also! :)

Comment: can i make the "eclipse" task run automaticaly when i click "refresh-all" ?

Comment: @AwanishRaj - dont want to downvote this since this the answer. please add information about the answer here. A few lines should be fine.
Or you can mark this question as duplicate if it is. 
thanks

Answer (score 6):

Also, i found this while searching for information on including projects/modules that are not in the same path:

https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/

It explains what Awanish Raj explained above, and more.