# settings.gradle: include one module vs include two modules

Tags: android, gradle, library-project

I have a library project (module `somelibrary`) that will be used both in an Android project and a desktop app project in `/Projects/SomeLibrary`.

The Android project (module `app`) is in `/Projects/AndroidApp`
and the desktop app (module `desktop`) project is in `/Projects/DesktopApp`.

There are two answers for this case in SO.

[Sync shared library projects/modules with its source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358724/sync-shared-library-projects-modules-with-its-source/31524641#31524641)

[Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle/17490233#17490233)

The first approach generates `settings.gradle` in the Android project

```
include ':app', ':somelibrary'
project(':somelibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SomeLibrary')
```

and `settings.gradle` in the desktop project

```
include ':desktop', ':somelibrary'
project(':somelibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SomeLibrary')
```

The second approach generates `settings.gradle` in the Android project

```
include ':somelibrary'
project(':somelibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SomeLibrary')
```

and `settings.gradle` in the desktop project (the same)

```
include ':somelibrary'
project(':somelibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SomeLibrary')
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score -1):

It's the same approach, except that you have an additonal module in each build, `desktop` and `app` respectively.