# Gradle - Could not find method wrapper() - dependant projects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

My project structure looks like bellow:

```
-Main dir
  - .gradle-wrapper
  |  - gradle-wrapper.jar
  |  - gradle-wrapper.properties
  |
  - projects
     - library
     - library-consumer
```

Inside `library` and `library-consumer` I have both `build.gradle` with:

```
wrapper {
    jarFile = "${project.projectDir}/../../.gradle-wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar"
    gradleVersion = '4.8.1'
}
```

Also, in project `library-consumer` I have in `build.gradle` dependency to `library` project as

```
compile project(':library')
```

In `library-consumer`'s `settings.gradle` I have included `library` like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358724/sync-shared-library-projects-modules-with-its-source/31524641#31524641):

```
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File("../library")
```

Then I receive following error while trying `gradle build`:

```
Could not find method wrapper() for arguments [build_7cibagmqy9u5sctvqdtah2a8p$_run_closure1@134371ea] on project ':library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Any sugestion/solution? Both projects has included changed path to wrapper like bellow:

```
set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\..\..\.gradle-wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar
```

`library` builds without problem.

Comment: Do you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Bahu No, unfortunately not, I made one "master build" which has wrapper definition and subprojects :/

Answer (score 0):

In gradle versions below version 5, you had to declare a wrapper task rather than attempting to configure an existing one.

See the upgrade guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#rel4.8:configure_internal_tasks).

It looks like you have not upgrade to version 5, so you need to do:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    jarFile = "${project.projectDir}/../../.gradle-wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar"
    gradleVersion = '4.8.1'
}
```